# The activity activityId could not be found (Parameter 'activityId')

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

For workitems i make
**/appbundles = "NamiliftActivity"** and **appbundles/:id/aliases "beta"**

---

but while sending data on /workitems

```js
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/workitems',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ******',
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
        activityId: 'BAsBRLiyiaHR1X9eYiAI4ATPmdcuZ5Pf.NamiliftActivity+beta',
        arguments: {
          InventorDoc: {
             url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/1a2ac1d9-a8af-4aa2-b9d1-8b0fde21bcf3?region=US',
             pathInZip: 'MasterAssembly.iam'
          },
          InventorParams: {
            url: 'data:application/json,{"ProjectNumber":"12345","ProjectName":"8000-2016","PreparedBy":"Nami","DrawingNumber":"Nami","CommissionNumber":"","ElevatorDesignation":"","ElevatorNumber":"","Logo":"NamiLift","LanguageOptions":"ENG","Standard":"PL400","NumberOfFloor":2,"LengthOfCar":2000,"WidthOfCar":1100,"Pits":true,"PitHeight":50,"ZoneSectionStart":239,"HeightAboveTopElevator":0,"ElectricBoxSide":"a","ElectricBoxFloorNo":"0","ElectricBoxDefault":false,"OuterRoof":false,"OuterRoofSide":"A","WindowsSectionA":"0-0","WindowsSectionB":"0-5000","WindowsSectionC":"0-0","WindowsSectionD":"0-0","DefaultDoorSize":false,"Colorelevator":"RAL 9001","Colordoor":"RAL 9001","Safelinemx2":false,"Safelinemx2gsm":false,"Schoolcontrolassa":false,"Schoolcontrol":false,"Intercom":false,"Callsend":false,"Firealarmdrive":false,"Folderseat":false,"Floorvoiceannouncement":false,"Lsfcable":false,"Telephone":false,"Keyswitch":false,"Ups":false,"Comments":"-","LiftHeightLevel0":0,"DoorSideLevel0":"A","TypeOfDoorLevel0":"A1","DoorHingeLevel0":"Right","DoorSizeLevel0":900,"DoorHeightLevel0":2000,"DoorCloserLevel0":true,"CanopyLevel0":true,"CallBoxLevel0":true,"LiftHeightLevel1":5000,"DoorSideLevel1":"A","TypeOfDoorLevel1":"A1","DoorHingeLevel1":"Right","DoorSizeLevel1":900,"DoorHeightLevel1":2000,"DoorCloserLevel1":false,"CanopyLevel1":false,"CallBoxLevel1":false}',
            OutputPDF: 'OutputPDF': {
                    'url': fileName.resultZipUrl,
                    'headers': {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + values.access_token,
                        'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
                    },
                    'verb': 'put'
            },
            onComplete: 'onComplete': {
                    'verb': 'post',
                    'url': config.credentials.callback_url +'/api/forge/datamanagement/signanddownload'
            }
       }
    }
})
```

I am getting this ***ERROR***
[image: The activity BAsBRLiyiaHR1X9eYiAI4ATPmdcuZ5Pf.NamiliftActivity+beta could not be found (Parameter 'activityId')]

```
The activity BAsBRLiyiaHR1X9eYiAI4ATPmdcuZ5Pf.NamiliftActivity+beta could not be found (Parameter 'activityId')
```

---

And appbundles id already set for workItems

[da-manager.autodesk](https://da-manager.autodesk.io/#)
[image: da-manager.autodesk]

This is /aliases for finding that particular beta activity
[image: da/us-east/v3/appbundles/:id/aliases]

[image: da/us-east/v3/appbundles]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity and Appbundles are 2 different concepts / entities. You have named your AppBundle `NamiliftActivity`, which is not an issue. You can name it anything as long as it uses allowed characters.

The error you have:

> The activity BAsBRLiyiaHR1X9eYiAI4ATPmdcuZ5Pf.NamiliftActivity+beta could not be found (Parameter 'activityId')

is exactly what it says. There is no such **Activity** `NamiliftActivity` with an alias `beta`. Or is there? Your post only shows an **AppBundle** with that name+alias.

Comment: Thanks Rahul ...i was confuse between appbundles and activities forgeapps[nickname]->appbundles[id]->activities[apps]->workitems[activityId]

Comment: Yes, you have the reference order correct now :).